# Помогите сформировать SQL запрос для импорта из таблицы в таблицу

Tags: mysql, linux

Помогите пожалуйста сформировать запрос.
Есть 2 таблицы: users и data

1. | fio | ip | sw_port |
   | --- | --- | --- |
2. | switch | port | ip |
   | --- | --- | --- |

Нужно импортировать значение из data.switch в users.sw_port, при этом выборочно задать соответсвтие по столбцам ip из обоих таблиц.
Пробовал сформировать такой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO users (sw_port)
SELECT t1.switch
FROM  data t1
JOIN users t2 ON t2.ip = t1.ip
WHERE t1.ip IS NOT NULL;
```

Но после запроса выходит ошибка:

| #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'name'. |
| --- |

Гугление ничего не дало, подскажите можно ли такое провернуть средствами SQL?

Comment: У вас в users таблице уже есть записи и вы хотите обновить их, а не создать новые?

Comment: Выложите пример данных (в формате CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO скриптов, 3-5 записей достаточно) и покажите требуемое конечное состояние данных для этих данных.

Comment: В таблице users есть записи, и их много. Я создал новый столбец пустой, назвал его sw_port и пытаюсь туда перенести инфу о портах на коммутаторе. Пробовал через REPLACE делать, но тогда он просто новую строку создает а не добавляет значения в столбец sw_port к нужной строке по ip адресу. То же самое происходит даже если я просто указываю REPLACE INTO users (mac) VALUES ('1') к примеру. Смысл в том что не совсем понимаю как в нужную строку попасть.

Answer (score 0):

Да такое можно сделать.
Если тебе нужно скопировать все колонки из одной таблицы в другу

```sql
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Если тебе нужно только часть колонок

```sql
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Это конечно понятно. Но боюсь что мне нужно перенести так что-бы выборка по столбцам ip была. Т.е. строку переносить только туда где совпадают ip-адреса в двух таблицах.

Comment: Так что мешает вписать условие в блок WHERE @JerichoCane

Comment: Честно говоря не совсем понимаю как через блок WHERE это сделать. Нужно тогда прежде два SELECT запроса сформировать что-бы выборку сделать по ip = ip?

Comment: @JerichoCane Тебе ничего не мешает сделать что то на подобии WHERE table1.ip = table2.ip.

Comment: @JerichoCane [пример1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from), [пример2](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: Если сформировать такой запрос INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE table1.column1 = table2.column1 выдает ошибку ; #1054 - Unknown column 'table2.column1' in 'where clause'. Я понимаю что это значит, но не понимаю как ее обойти. Иными словами блок WHERE не знает о такой таблице table2.column1.

Comment: @JerichoCane там по идее нужно в начале сделать JOIN чтобы получилось промежуточная таблица с нужными значениями, а потом эту промежуточную таблицу вмерджить в ту которую тебе надо.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую